# Overflowing layout with TableLayout

Tags: java, codenameone, layout-manager, tablelayout

I need to show three things in a row in a sort of table. The first column should have a fixed width of say 15% of the screen. The third one should be right aligned and take its preferred width. The second one should take all the remaining space (I'll need to add some spacing, but that's another story).

This happens in `start`:

```
    final Container list = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
    list.setScrollableY(true);
    final String[][] lines = {
            {"19", "Some text", "123,00"},
            {"20", "Some very very very very looong text", "1,00"},
    };
    for(final String[] line : lines) list.add(createContainer(line));
    form.add(list);
```

The container is rather trivial:

```
private Container createContainer(String[] line) {
    final TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(1, 3);
    tableLayout.setGrowHorizontally(true);
    final Container result = new Container(tableLayout);
    {
        final Label l = new Label(line[0]);
        l.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0x0000FF);
        result.add(tableLayout.createConstraint().widthPercentage(15), l);
    }
    {
        final Label l = new Label(emptyToSpace(line[1]));
        l.getAllStyles().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_MEDIUM));
        result.add(tableLayout.createConstraint().widthPercentage(-2), l);
    }
    {
        final Label l = new Label(line[2]);
        l.getAllStyles().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_LARGE));
        l.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0x00FF00);
        result.add(tableLayout.createConstraint().widthPercentage(-1).horizontalAlign(Component.RIGHT), l);
    }
    return result;
}
```

According to the javadoc, `-1` means preferred size and `-2` means "remaining space". It sort of works, but there seem to be a miscalculation.

The problem happens in the simulator, no matter what device I choose. I may be doing it all wrong, as I'm new to codenameone layouts.

[image: overflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -2 flag is mostly optimized for the last column so this looks like a bug but might be hard to workaround. I don't see a need to use table layout here since you don't use one table which would provide alignment between the rows.

A simpler approach would be border layout e.g.:

```
Container c = BorderLayout.centerEastWest(new Label(emptyToSpace(line[1])), 
                   rightText, leftText);
```

If you want the left column to align just use `Component.setSameWidth()` on the entire column.

Comment: This works, but `Component.setSameWidth()` on all "wests" is rather impractical as I have to collect them all for the call. What's worse is that on click, I replace one row by an expanded version (the middle text in `SpanLabel` and some minor visual changes to other parts), so I have to re-collect them. Do I have to call `Component.setSameWidth(theNoMoreUsedWestComponent)` in order to prevent a memory leak?

Comment: If you reuse components a lot then yes you should call it but for realistic usage I doubt there will be a leak as the entire form will be GC'd. An alternative approach would be to use one table layout with two columns and as many rows as you have items. Add the first column as the aligned number. Then use border layout with the center and right side only as before.